# "Use of property 'nibName' in base object before super.init initializes it" after updating to Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, xcode6.1

I have this code in my iOS app, written in Swift:

```
class AddHomeViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    ...

    required override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) 
    {
        super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: nibBundle)
    }
```

After updating to Xcode 6.1, I get these errors on the `super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: nibBundle)` line. It worked perfectly before:

```
Use of property 'nibName' in base object before super.init initializes it

Use of property 'nibBundle' in base object before super.init initializes it
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the `super.init()` line to use the `OrNil` arguments fixes the issue:

```
super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
```

Comment: Hi, do you know why we simply can't use `nibName` or `nibBundle`? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to figure that out, @Unheilig - no idea. That might be good material for a new question.